# Sitecore MVC Unity Solr issue

Tags: model-view-controller, solr, sitecore

I am new to Sitecore,SoleNet. I have installed and configured Solr to work with Sitecore and I am able to see results. 
I am now using code.

I added the connection string to UnityMVCActivator.cs in the Start()
Startup.Init("http://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index");

In my controller - Actionresults Index()
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance>();

I get this error

> [InvalidOperationException: The type ISolrOperations1 does not have an
>   accessible constructor.]
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForNullExistingObject(IBuilderContext
>   context) +226 lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +39
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +33
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +337
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +396 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type
>   t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable1 resolverOverrides) +238
>
> [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = "SolrNet.ISolrOperations`1[Niddk.Model.SearchResultsViewModel]", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ISolrOperations`1 does not have an accessible constructor.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

> Resolving
>   SolrNet.ISolrOperations1[Niddk.Model.SearchResultsViewModel],(none) ]
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable1 resolverOverrides) +500
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name,
>   ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +20
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) +55
>
> [ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get
>   instance of type ISolrOperations1, key ""]
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) +156
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance()
>   +62 Niddk.Web.Controllers.SearchController.Index() in C:\Users\ksivanandan\Source\Repos\web\Niddk\Niddk.Web\Controllers\SearchController.cs:23
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +229
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2
>   parameters) +35
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   +80 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +453
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +453
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +533

My ViewModel

```
public class SearchResultsViewModel
{

    [SolrField("headline_t")]
    public string Headline { get; set; }


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: this thread was also raised in GitHub in SolrNet and the project maintainer provided the right answer.

The problem is that for registering he is using the built in IoC but then resolving via Unity.

**Original response**
I may be reading your code wrong or something might be missing from the post but you are not passing the type:

In my controller - Actionresults Index()

`var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<[you are missing this part]>();`

When using generics you need to specify the type. I thinks this part would not even compile because of the .GetInstance>() being incomplete.

Comment: I would guess that the code sample was messed up in the copy/paste to SO

Comment: Yes that was the original comment. I expanded to include the real response as provided by SolrNet's maintainer.